# How to convert a nested dictionary's keys in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and want to store a nested dictionary keys as rows in a pandas dataframe. Specifically, here is how the dictionary looks like:

```
apicalls= [{'GetNativeSystemInfo': 1, 'DeviceIoControl': 2, 'RegCloseKey': 1, 'NtDuplicateObject': 
 1,'NtSetInformationFile': 5,{'NtDuplicateObject': 3, 'DeviceIoControl': 1, 'GetVolumePathNameW': 1, 'RegCloseKey': 1, 'NtQueryKey': 2,'NtQueryValueKey': 6}, {'LdrUnloadDll': 1, 'LdrGetDllHandle': 2, 'NtCreateSection': 1, 'NtOpenKey': 3, 'LdrGetProcedureAddress': 4, 'SetUnhandledExceptionFilter': 5}]
```

The above are list of API calls extracted from 3 executable files during dynamic analysis.

I have tried to generate the data frame using the following line of code, but it is not giving me what I want.

```
api_frame = pd.DataFrame(apicalls)
```

I want the data frame that looks like the one below. kindly help.

[image]

Comment: Your output image is not clear, could you update it, please?

Comment: sorry, I have now updated the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data sample you provided does not follow the python syntax, I assumed that the data looks like this:

```
apicalls = [
    {'GetNativeSystemInfo': 1, 'DeviceIoControl': 2, 'RegCloseKey': 1, 'NtDuplicateObject': 1,'NtSetInformationFile': 5},
    {'NtDuplicateObject': 3, 'DeviceIoControl': 1, 'GetVolumePathNameW': 1, 'RegCloseKey': 1, 'NtQueryKey': 2,'NtQueryValueKey': 6},
    {'LdrUnloadDll': 1, 'LdrGetDllHandle': 2, 'NtCreateSection': 1, 'NtOpenKey': 3, 'LdrGetProcedureAddress': 4, 'SetUnhandledExceptionFilter': 5}
]
```

You can simply loop over the list to get the keys for each dictionary using the `.keys()` method, and then pass that list to `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([call.keys() for call in apicalls])
```

This results in the following dataframe:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetNativeSystemInfo | DeviceIoControl | RegCloseKey | NtDuplicateObject | NtSetInformationFile |  |
| NtDuplicateObject | DeviceIoControl | GetVolumePathNameW | RegCloseKey | NtQueryKey | NtQueryValueKey |
| LdrUnloadDll | LdrGetDllHandle | NtCreateSection | NtOpenKey | LdrGetProcedureAddress | SetUnhandledExceptionFilter |

Comment: Hey @Oxbowerce thank you, this is exactly what I wanted . Just one more thing, when I use your code, I got None in the first row, under column 5 (cell 6). How can I remove it and keep the cell empty as it looks in your data frame?. For other rows it's fine.

Comment: That cell will be null since there is no fifth value for that row, when converting it to markdown it will simply be an empty string. If you want any null values to actually be an empty string, you can use the [`.fillna()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), which allows you to fill all na/null values with a specific value.

Comment: I used both methods and they worked well. Many thanks @ Oxbowerce